# Running one of two queries based on the content of a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a query which works on certain condition

```
query1 =query('KEY WORK'!A1:I200,"select A,B,C,D where E = '"&B8&"' and A = '"&B4&"' and I = FALSE",)

query2 =query('KEY WORK'!A1:I200,"select A,B,C,D where E = '"&B8&"' and A = '"&B4&"' and I = TRUE",)
```

Now My problem is that I want to use if function and it should be like this:

```
=if(B4="ALL" then run Query1 else Query2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the IF command when forming the query string.

```
query1 =query('KEY WORK'!A1:I200, "select A,B,C,D where E = '"&B8&"' and A = '"&B4&"' and I = "&if(B4="ALL", "FALSE", "TRUE"))
```

The second parameter of `query` is just a string that you can form using whatever spreadsheet logic is available for string formation.